# groupby 2 columns and count into separate columns based on one columns cases

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to group by 2 columns of which the first value has 5 different values and the second 2.

My data looks like this:

[image]

and using

```py
df_counted = df_analysis
                 .groupby(['TYPE', 'RESULT'])
                 .size()
                 .sort_values(ascending=False) 
                 .reset_index(name='COUNT')
```

I was able to transform it into the cases I want:

[image]

However I don't want a column for result, just for counts.

It's suppoed to be like

```
          COUNT_TRUE  COUNT_FALSE
FORWARD           21          182                  
BACKWARD          34          170
RIGHT             24          298   
LEFT              20          242
NEUTRAL           16           82
```

The best I could do there was this. How do I get there?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has a feature of making a pivot table with dataframe. Your task can also be done by making pivot table.

```
df_counted.pivot_table(index="TYPE", columns="RESULT", values="COUNT")
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it and went a kind of full SQL there. It's not elegant, but it works:

`df_counted` is the last `df` from the question with the `NaN` values.

```py
# drop duplicates for the first counts
df_pos = df_counted.drop_duplicates(subset=['TYPE'], keep='first').drop(columns=['COUNT_POS'])

# drop duplicates for the first counts
df_neg = df_counted.drop_duplicates(subset=['TYPE'], keep='last').drop(columns=['COUNT_NEG'])

# join on TYPE
df = df_pos.set_index('TYPE').join(df_neg.set_index('TYPE'))
```

[image]

If someone has a more elegant way of doing this, I'd be super interested to see it.